# Latitude and Longitude radius

Tags: geocoding, latitude-longitude

I am working on app in which i am first sending user Latitude and Longitude to the server .  Server also has some previously stored coordinates, Now the app has to check if the user coordinate is within a radius of 1km or 2km of coordinates server already have.

One approach i found is of taking initial coordinate as circle center but it is not accurate.
Any suggestion which algorithm i should follow and source which can help me understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    R  =  6378.1;  //  radius of the Earth (km)
    dlat = deg2rad( $lat1-$lat2 ) // lattitude diference in radians
    dlang = deg2rad ( $lang1 - $lang2 ) //longitude diference in radian
```

The Radius of the Earth is much bigger than 1-2 km , so we can use Pythagoras theorm, and we made 0.03 % accuracy ~ 0.3 m.

```
   distance = R * sqrt( $dlat^2 + $dlang^2  );
   // same:   distance =  sqrt( ($dlat*R)^2 + ($dlang*R)^2)   )
```

This may help you to understand:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Spherical coordinate system not the same as geolocation coordinate system, but to understand what you need, i think the below link has a good explain.

If you need more accurancy:
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance at **Worked example** section

When the distances only a few kilometers, the accuracy difference is small, but the computing time is much better when use the formula I wrote.